# Unable to connect to MySQL on Rasberry Pi using Java Client

Tags: java, mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I have installed MySQL Server on Raspberry Pi Zero W along with Apache 2 and Tomcat 7 needed for my application.

However I am unable to log in from my java application to my MySQL Server. I'm getting the following error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Client does not support authentication protocol
>   requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client

Comment: Which client/API/library is using your java application using? Which version is the mysql client/API/library you are using. Also, please edit your question to include the source code of your java application, with the full error message (and stacktrace).

Answer (score 0):

Have you start the server?

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: Yes, The server is started. When I connect using mysql -u -p I get this message : 

         Welcome to the MariaDB monitor. Commands end with ; or \g. 
         Your MariaDB connection id is 13 
         Server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0 
         Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others. 
         Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement. 

But I'm unable to connect from my Java Client